# Check if value is available in a list or not along with available value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008, I have table with records like these,

```
Name
----
John
Amy
Peter
Jack
Alan
Linda
```

I have another list of user ('John', 'Adam', 'Amy', 'Frank')
How do I check that which user in list is in table and not, without creating temp table

Expected output table

```
Name   Available
----   ---------
John   John
Adam   Null
Amy    Amy
Frank  Null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use row constructors to avoid having to explicitly create a temp table.

Using `EXISTS` rather than an `OUTER JOIN` might be more efficient if there can be duplicates of names in your base table (it can stop the seek as soon as the first matching record is found for a name).

```
SELECT name,
       CASE
              WHEN EXISTS
                     (SELECT *
                     FROM    yourtable t
                     WHERE   t.name = names.name
                     )
              THEN names.name
       END AS Available
FROM   (VALUES
       ('John'), ( 'Adam'),( 'Amy'), ('Frank') ) names (name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just need a left (or right) join on your two tables, something like:

```
select n.name, u.name
from names n
  left join users u on n.name=u.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpNames (UserName varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #tmpNames
VALUES ('John'), ('Adam'), ('Amy'), ('Frank');

SELECT t.UserName AS Name, myTable.Name AS Available
FROM #tmpNames t
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable m ON t.UserName = m.name
```

Edit: The solution assumes that names in the table and the list are unique; otherwise, there is the potential for duplicate rows in the results.

Comment: @Martin: You're assuming names are not unique, I'm assuming names are unique based on the sample data.  However, I should state my assumptions and will edit.  thanks.